# How to wrap this content inside my shortcode? It´s content that resides in a template php file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to wrap the content of the template php file, inside a shortcode, that has a closing tag. The shortcode looks like this:

```
[hide for="!administrator, !subscriber"]'content goes here??'[/hide]
```

This code hides the content for anyone besides the two user-roles administrator and subscriber.

The issue i have is, how do i wrap the shortcode around the entire list item element?

The code that needs to be wrapped inside the shortcode provided above is:

```
<?php
/**
 * `Call now` quick action.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */

if ( ! ( $phone = $listing->get_field('phone') ) ) {
    return;
}

$link = sprintf( 'tel:%s', $phone );
?>

<li id="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['id'] ) ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['class'] ) ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ) ?>" rel="nofollow">
        <?php echo c27()->get_icon_markup( $action['icon'] ) ?>
        <span><?php echo $action['label'] ?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I have tried wrapping it in various ways but it makes the page unable to load.

I have tried the code like this:

```
?php echo do_shortcode('[hide for="!administrator, !subscriber"]'All the content is put inside here'[/hide]');
```

But it doesnt work and ends up looking very messed up. I am not any sort of programmer so im finding this very difficult but i would assume that its possible. Also i know something like this should probably be done via the functions.php file in my child theme, instead of within this template file in the main theme but i just cant figure out how to write a function for this.

Will appreciate any kind of help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already editing the PHP you don't need to use the shortcodes that are hiding anything. You can simply do a check of current user role.

```
<?php
/**
 * `Call now` quick action.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */

if ( ! ( $phone = $listing->get_field('phone') ) )
    return;

// if you want to not display anything for guests
if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    return;

// if you want to not display anything for anyone but administrator or subscriber
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && !in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) 
    return;

$link = sprintf( 'tel:%s', $phone );
?>

<li id="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['id'] ) ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['class'] ) ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ) ?>" rel="nofollow">
        <?php echo c27()->get_icon_markup( $action['icon'] ) ?>
        <span><?php echo $action['label'] ?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Maximus Light. Thanks for your reply :) Appreciate it. Would you mind posting how the entire code should look like? With the content inside the shortcode? Thanks alot for it

Comment: Added the EDIT2, you actually don't need to do a shortcode there and can do the check directly with PHP. But If you still REALLY need to use shortcode for any reasons let me know.

Comment: Okay it seems to work BUT it hides it for my administrator user too.. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I appreciate all your good help so far on this matter. Hope you can reply with the fix for why it doesnt show for adminstrator and subscriber. Because then your solution is much better than using shortcode for me.

Comment: Not sure why it wont work. Anyway, are you just trying to hide content from guests? if yes, simply remove the 
**$user = wp_get_current_user();if ( !in_array( array('subscriber', 'administrator'), (array) $user->roles ) )  return;** part

Comment: No that content needs to be hidden from everybody except adminstrator and subscriber role. Also hidden for non-logged in users of the website.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I don't use discord, but you can always ask a question in the stackoverflow surely someone will help you. thumbs up.

Comment: Maximus, its because i have two other elements i need to hide in the same way.. But they reside in other parts of my theme.. And im guessing the same code wont work.. Should be handled via the functions.php file im pretty sure would be best so its not overwritten when theme updates, which is the problem im facing with doing this..

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom Shortcode function in your Wordpress functions.php file.

Not exactly sure of what your trying to do but maybe this helps...

In the WYSIWYG:

```
[hide] Your content...[/hide]
```

In PHP:

```
<?= do_shortcode('[hide]'.$yourcontent.'[/hide]' );?>
```

In functions.php

```
function hide_func($atts, $content=""){
    return '<span style="display:none">'.$content.'</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'hide', 'hide_func');
```